# Warning in Xcode that won't go away! (Entitlements with FileProtection)

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

Hey just became a new iOS developer and everything is fine and dandy so far but I have a warning in Xcode for my .xcodeproj file and it says "Validate Project Settings - Update to recommended settings." When I click on it I get a window that says "Target '(my app name)' - Upgrade DataProtectionClass Entitlement. Upgrades the default file protection level for your application to the recommended value: NSFileProtectionComplete." So I go ahead and click on perform changes so it can do that and the warning goes away but when I try to debug on device I get the error "The entitlements specified in your application's Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

If I remove the entitlemnets file which upgraded the default file protection to NSFileProtectionComplete then the wanring in Xcode goes away and it is able to compile and run on the device but then I have the issue of having a warning in xcode that doesn't want to budge.

This happens with a brand new project as well. I'm running Xcode Version 4.4 (4F134) on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion DP3 (12A178q).

In terminal I went ahead and looked at the entitlements of my .mobileprovision file. (not the wildcard one, but the one with the specific app id)

```
security cms -D -i /pathto.mobileprovision
```

And I got this value for the Entitlements key.

```
 <key>Entitlements</key>
 <dict>
      <key>application-identifier</key>
      <string>GLAMURY37G.com.ionescuac.GPS-Status-</string>
      <key>get-task-allow</key>
      <true/>
      <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
      <array>
           <string>GLAMURY37G.*</string>
      </array>
 </dict>
```

When I built the app in xcode for debug configuration I went ahead and looked at it's entitlements with

```
codesign -d --entitlements - /pathtoapplication.app
```

And got this back

```
<dict>
     <key>application-identifier</key>
     <string>GLAMURY37G.com.ionescuac.GPS-Status-</string>
     <key>get-task-allow</key>
     <true/>
     <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
     <array>
          <string>GLAMURY37G.com.ionescuac.GPS-Status-</string>
     </array>
</dict>
```

And it matches so as expected xcode can run the app on the device. But, xcode is telling me to upgrade to FileProtectionComplete so I do that and then after building my app and checking the app's entitlements again this is what I get.

```
<dict>
     <key>DataProtectionClass</key>
     <string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
     <key>application-identifier</key>
     <string>GLAMURY37G.com.ionescuac.GPS-Status-</string>
     <key>get-task-allow</key>
     <true/>
</dict>
```

Which makes it NOT match anymore so then I get the error in my first post. If I sign it with the FileProtectionComplete entitlements then xcode gives no warning but it can't run anymore. If I build it without the entitlements then it will run but xcode will keep nagging me with this warning that the FileProtection entitlements should be upgraded to their "recommended settings."

Kinda stuck in a catch 22 situation. Before I joined the developer program I messed around a lot with the simulator and never had any entitlement issues with xcode saying that they needed to be added to the build.

Comment: The funny part is, the DataProtectionClass entitlement isn't actually working in the latest iOS versions. This is according to some Apple guys on the dev forums.

Comment: I think I saw those posts and I have no idea why xcode is recommending me to put that entitlement in. It's completely bugged (at least according to how I see it). It's just annoying to have that yellow triangle keep popping up.

Comment: I know that certain entitlements can be excluded or added without causing a conflict with the entitlements defined in the provisioning profile. Clearly this isn't the case with the DataProtectionClass. I think your best bet is just to ignore the warning. You might also try using the .entitlements file only in Release mode by changing the appropriate build settings.